# How to make Django work with MySQL Connector/Python?

Tags: python, mysql, django, mysql-connector, django-database

Has anyone made Django work with myconnpy?

I've checked out http://github.com/rtyler/connector-django-mysql but
the author said it's very outdated and not supported.

If you've managed to make Django work with myconnpy, please share your
experience.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed something similar, so I forked the project you linked to and updated it to work (for small values of) with Django 1.2's newer database backend API.

It should be noted that my use case is very simple (read access to a single table on a single database) and I have not tested it with anything more than that.

You can find it at http://github.com/jerith/connector-django-mysql